# Add multiple columns based on unique entries in other column in csv with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I've done some basic work with powershell over the last year, but for some reason this is evading me.  Any help would be appreciated.

I have a csv file that will have several hundred entries:

```
Path,Data,Files
\\someserver\somepath1,100,1
\\someserver\somepath2,150,4
\\someserver\somepath1,200,5
\\someserver\somepath3,450,8
\\someserver\somepath4,200,23
\\someserver\somepath1,350,2
\\someserver\somepath2,800,9
```

I'd like to have the powershell script parse through the file and produce a new csv with results that show the unique paths and summed data and files values.  So from the above my expected results would be (preferrably sorted by largest data value):

```
Path,Data,Files
\\someserver\somepath2,950,9
\\someserver\somepath1,650,8
\\someserver\somepath3,450,8
\\someserver\somepath4,200,23
```

I've found several answers referring to summing a single column, but I haven't figured out it out for two columns yet.  Any suggestions on both code and/or technique would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ugly code ...

```
$csv=Import-Csv c:\temp\test.csv 
$csv | select -Unique -expand path|%{
    $path=$_
    $sdata=($csv | ?{$_.path -eq $path} | measure-object data -sum).sum
    $files=($csv | ?{$_.path -eq $path} |  Measure-Object files -sum).sum   
    "$path,$sdata,$files" |out-file c:\temp\new.csv -append
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Far less elegant solution then Kayasax but still functional. This will cycle though each entry building and array as it goes along. When it find a Path that already exists in the array it then adds the values of data and files. Also this outputs an object that your can use powershell commands against!

```
$collection = @()
Import-Csv E:\temp\stack.csv | ForEach-Object{
    If ($collection.Count -gt 0) {
        If ($collection.path.IndexOf($_.Path) -ne -1){
            # We already know about this path. Add Values
            $index = $collection.path.IndexOf($_.Path)
            $collection[$index].Data = [int]$collection[$index].Data + [int]$_.Data
            $collection[$index].Files = [int]$collection[$index].Files + [int]$_.Files
        } Else {
            # Add this objec to the collection
            $properties = @{'Path'=$_.Path;
                        'Data'=$_.Data;
                        'Files'=$_.Files}
            $object = New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop $properties
            $collection += $object
        }
    } Else {
        # Collection is empty. Add the first one. 
        $properties = @{'Path'=$_.Path;
                    'Data'=$_.Data;
                    'Files'=$_.Files}
        $object = New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop $properties
        $collection += $object
    }
}

$collection | Sort-Object data -Descending
```

**output**

```
Path                                             Data                     Files
----                                             ----                     -----
\\someserver\somepath2                            950                        13
\\someserver\somepath1                            650                         8
\\someserver\somepath3                            450                         8
\\someserver\somepath4                            200                        23
```

Comment: Nom file value for 2nd and 3rd records?

Comment: If you are asking about the number of files for both path 1 and 3 its correct? 1+5+2=8 and the other only has the one entry. I dont understand what the issue is?