# how do you retrieve timestamp and put into a csv file with get-vmhost command in powershell?

Tags: powershell, vcenter

I would like to put the output of get-vmhost to a csv file with a timestamp. Get-vmhost command does not have a timestamp output, I tried to do timestamp=(get-date), but when I tried to use the pipe, it is giving me an error. Any ideas how I could insert a timestamp column in that csv file with values?

```
if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name VMware.VimAutomation.Core -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
{
Add-PSsnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core
}

$Server="dc1-vc.example.com"
Connect-VIServer -server $Server -User <id> -Password <pass>
$Timestamp=(get-date)
Get-VMHost | Where-Object {$_.PowerState -eq "PoweredOn"} | Select-Object Timestamp, Name, NumCpu, CpuUsageMhz, CpuTotalMhz, MemoryUsageGB, MemoryTotalGB |

ConvertTo-Csv  -NoTypeInformation |Out-File -Append -Encoding ascii -FilePath "c:\output\new_dc1.csv"

Disconnect-VIServer -Server $Server -Confirm:$false
```

The error:

```
 The term 'Timestamp=' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, scri
    pt file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
    included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: The error itself is because you want to be assigning a variable? So it should be `$Timestamp=(get-date)`

Comment: TimeStamp will be null when you output it from the select statement since it is not a property of `Get-VMHost`. You are looking for adding a column to an object or array. There are several option you will find on SO like this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426089/add-multiple-columns-based-on-unique-entries-in-other-column-in-csv-with-powersh/25427666#25427666). The first answer, not mine, would be the easiest for you to assimilate into your code.

Comment: @Matt, on your second comment, how would I do that? I missed the $ in my post.

Comment: The error in your question has been address and not longer needs to be in the code. You corrected your typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Timestamp=(get-date)
Get-VMHost | Where-Object {$_.PowerState -eq "PoweredOn"} | ForEach-Object{
    "$Timestamp,$($_.Name),$($_.NumCpu),$($_.CpuUsageMhz),$($_.CpuTotalMhz),$($_.MemoryUsageGB),$($_.MemoryTotalGB)" | 
        Out-File -Append -Encoding ascii -FilePath "c:\output\new_dc1.csv"
}
```

Using the filter you specified build a small comma delimited string using the properties you desire with the addition of the `$Timestamp` created earlier. For each Vm output the formatted code to the file.

Let me know if you have issues so i can update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this:
`Get-VMHost | Where-Object {$_.PowerState -eq "PoweredOn"} | 
Select-Object @{Name="Timestamp";Expression={$Timestamp}}, Name, NumCpu, CpuUsageMhz, CpuTotalMhz, MemoryUsageGB, MemoryTotalGB |
ConvertTo-Csv  -NoTypeInformation |Out-File -Append -Encoding ascii -FilePath "c:\output\new_dc1.csv"`